# python querying a json objectpath

Tags: python, json

I've a nested json structure, I'm using objectpath (python API version), but I don't understand how to select and filter some information (more precisely the nested information in the structure).

EG.
I want to select the "description" of the action "reading" for the user "John".

JSON:

```
{
    "user": 
    {
            "actions":   
             [
                 {
                 "name": "reading",
                 "description": "blablabla"
                 }
             ]
            "name": "John"
    }
}
```

CODE:

```
$.user[@.name is 'John' and @.actions.name is 'reading'].actions.description
```

but it doesn't work (empty set but in my JSON it isn't so).
Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think this is even valid JSON.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: Yeah, he has a `name: value` inside an array.

Comment: Why is this tagged python? You're asking how to use some JavaScript library in JavaScript to parse some JSON.

Comment: I'm using the python version of the library and it has some features that the javascript version don't have.

Comment: There's a group where you can ask Qs about ObjectPath if something doesn't work as expected https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/objectpath

Comment: This question is busted until you fix your JSON. However, I answered it based on my best guess of what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import objectpath

data = {
    "user": {
        "actions": {
                "name": "reading",
                "description": "blablabla"
            },
        "name": "John"
    }
}

tree = objectpath.Tree(data)
result = tree.execute("$.user[@.name is 'John'].actions[@.name is 'reading'].description")
for entry in result:
    print entry
```

**Output**

```
blablabla
```

I had to fix your JSON. Also, `tree.execute` returns a generator. You could replace the `for` loop with `print result.next()`, but the `for` loop seemed more clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
import objectpath import *

your_json = {"name": "felix", "last_name": "diaz"}

# This json path will bring all the key-values of your json

your_json_path='$.*'

my_key_values = Tree(your_json).execute(your_json_path)

# If you want to retrieve the name node...then specify it. 
my_name= Tree(your_json).execute('$.name')

# If you want to retrieve a the last_name node...then specify it. 
last_name= Tree(your_json).execute('$.last_name')
```

Comment: Please include some explanation to make the example easier to understand. :-)

Comment: This does not answer the question and is even more confusing than the documentation (which is some of the worst I have ever seen).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're just missing a comma in JSON:

```
{
    "user": 
    {
        "actions": [
            {
                 "name": "reading",
                 "description": "blablabla"
            }
        ],
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

Assuming there is only one "John", with only one "reading" activity, the following query works:

```
$.user[@.name is 'John'].actions[0][@.name is 'reading'][0].description
```

---

If there could be multiple "John"s, with multiple "reading" activities, the following query will **almost** work:

```
$.user.*[@.name is 'John'].actions..*[@.name is 'reading'].description
```

I say **almost** because the use of `..` will be problematic if there are other nested dictionaries with "name" and "description" entries, such as

```
{
    "user": {
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "reading",
                "description": "blablabla",
                "nested": {
                    "name": "reading",
                    "description": "broken"
                }
            }
        ],
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

To get a correct query, there is an open issue to correctly implement queries into arrays: https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath/issues/60